# Need help optimizing a SOQL query

Tags: soql, query, performance, duplicate-management

I am writing a simple trigger to tag lead duplicates based on two different fields, Email and our internal Lead ID (which we keep consisted between our own server DB and salesforce via integration).

Here is the initial trigger setup and the queries themselves, but I am getting `Non-selective Query` errors...

```
Map<ID, String> dupeFinderMap = new Map<ID, String>();
Map<String, ID> leadEmailMap = new Map<String, ID>();
Map<String, ID> leadILIDMap = new Map<String, ID>();

if(!trigger.isDelete) {
    for (Lead l : trigger.new){
        dupeFinderMap.put(l.id, '');
        leadEmailMap.put(l.Email, l.id);
        leadILIDMap.put(l.Internal_Lead_ID__c, l.id);
    }
} else {
    for (Lead l : trigger.old) {
        dupeFinderMap.put(l.id, '');
        leadEmailMap.put(l.Email, l.id);
        leadILIDMap.put(l.Internal_Lead_ID__c, l.id);
    }
}

List<Lead> dupeEmailLeads = [SELECT Id, Email, Internal_Lead_ID__c FROM Lead WHERE Email IN :leadEmailMap.keySet() AND Id NOT IN :dupeFinderMap.keySet()];
List<Lead> dupePILIDLeads = [SELECT Id, Email, Internal_Lead_ID__c FROM Lead WHERE Internal_Lead_ID__c IN :leadPILIDMap.keySet() AND Id NOT IN :dupeFinderMap.keySet()];
```

Is it something to do with the fact that I'm checking against a map keyset?  Or is it the In or NOT IN conditions?  Is there a better way to build these queries?  My goal is to collect all Leads that have Email or Internal Lead ID the same as a Lead in the trigger, but are not in the trigger themselves.

Comment: When ever you are doing update or insert on before or after events you were looping though and creating the maps. One thing I noticed here every time you are creating all the maps and you used them in the query, if you observe closely in the where condition every record will have an instance in each map so the conditions it self fail to fetch the records. if you want to recheck write some debug logs and see weather you were fetching any records or not from your quries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check for null before adding email in Map, as it may have null or blank value. 
Other suggestion is dont use 'NOT' operator in SOQL. You should query all records and then iterate to check if email not exist in Apex.

Also you can combine two SOQL, Please try below code :

```
Map<ID, String> dupeFinderMap = new Map<ID, String>();
Map<String, ID> leadEmailMap = new Map<String, ID>();
Map<String, ID> leadILIDMap = new Map<String, ID>();

if(!trigger.isDelete) {
    for (Lead l : trigger.new){
        dupeFinderMap.put(l.id, '');
        if(l.Email != null && l.Email != '')
        {
            leadEmailMap.put(l.Email, l.id);
        }
        leadILIDMap.put(l.Internal_Lead_ID__c, l.id);
    }
} else {
    for (Lead l : trigger.old) {
        dupeFinderMap.put(l.id, '');
        if(l.Email != null && l.Email != '')
        {
            leadEmailMap.put(l.Email, l.id);
        }
        leadILIDMap.put(l.Internal_Lead_ID__c, l.id);
    }
}

List<Lead> dupeEmailLeads = null;
List<Lead> dupePILIDLeads = null;

if(!leadEmailMap.keySet().isEmpty())
{
    dupeEmailLeads = [SELECT Id, Email, Internal_Lead_ID__c FROM Lead WHERE Email IN :leadEmailMap.keySet() ]; 
}

if(!leadILIDMap.keySet().isEmpty())
{
    dupePILIDLeads = [SELECT Id, Email, Internal_Lead_ID__c FROM Lead WHERE Email Internal_Lead_ID__c IN :leadILIDMap.keySet()]; 
}

if(leadEmailMap != null)
{
    //Iterate through above records and process
}

if(leadILIDMap != null)
{
    //Iterate through above records and process
}
```

Please go though this documentation to understand [How to write efficient queries for LDV](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/en/cce/ldv_deployments/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.pdf) and [some high level LDV questions and answers](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/large-data-volumes-ldv-in-salesforce/).

Comment: I have done all of this, checked for null/blank email values used the single query exactly as you show here, but I am still getting `non-selective query` errors.

Comment: Ohhk, How many records do you have in Lead Object ?

Comment: In production we have almost 250k, but in the sandbox where I am building this we have zero (error occurs when I try to create one).

Comment: 250k is not big volume.. I have updated code, can you check ?

Comment: Nope, still giving the error when I try to save a new Lead...

Comment: Ok, Did you checked debug logs on which line its giving error ?

Comment: I just looked, it it only the second query that is causing the error.  So maybe it is because the Internal Lead ID field is not indexed.  I will look into that, thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah, You can make that field as external Id for time being and see if it resolves. After that you can raise case to index that field. Please mark if it answered your question.

Comment: Haha! So it turns out that the person who created the Internal Lead ID field forgot to check the 'External ID' option.  I went and checked it, so now the field is indexed and the query is working just fine.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The check id not in list will require the complete table scan which will error out when data is huge. Please try the below version.

```
Map<ID, String> dupeFinderMap = new Map<ID, String>();
Map<String, ID> leadEmailMap = new Map<String, ID>();
Map<String, ID> leadILIDMap = new Map<String, ID>();

if(!trigger.isDelete) {
    for (Lead l : trigger.new){
        dupeFinderMap.put(l.id, '');
        leadEmailMap.put(l.Email, l.id);
        leadILIDMap.put(l.Internal_Lead_ID__c, l.id);
    }
} else {
    for (Lead l : trigger.old) {
        dupeFinderMap.put(l.id, '');
        leadEmailMap.put(l.Email, l.id);
        leadILIDMap.put(l.Internal_Lead_ID__c, l.id);
    }
}
List<Lead> dupeEmailLeads = new List<Lead>();
List<Lead> dupePILIDLeads = new List<Lead>();
for( Lead l: [SELECT Id, Email, Internal_Lead_ID__c FROM Lead WHERE Email IN :leadEmailMap.keySet()])
{
    if(!dupeFinderMap.containksKey(l.id))
    {
        dupeEmailLeads.add(l);
    }
}

for(Lead L: [SELECT Id, Email, Internal_Lead_ID__c FROM Lead WHERE Internal_Lead_ID__c IN :leadPILIDMap.keySet()])
{
    if(!dupeFinderMap.containksKey(L.id))
    {
        dupePILIDLeads.add(l);
    }
}
```